# Get name and email claim using IdentityServer from Google auth (SPA)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm new to using Identity Server for SPA auth but I started following this example: [Authentication and authorization for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and with some tinkering I've now also added Google auth. However, I'm having trouble getting the external Google claims merged into my application's claims (for example: `given_name`).

I've verified that Google does send back the appropriate claims but nothing seems to map those claims, e.g. `options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");`. When I access one of my protected endpoints my claims do not include any of the additional google claims.

I did find some additional documentation [Persist additional claims...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0#map-user-data-keys-and-create-claims) which tells me to add the claim in `OnPostConfirmationAsync (Account/ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs)` but since this is an SPA that page doesn't exist. Is there another approach to this? I haven't been able to find much that doesn't use the `Page / OnPostConfirmationAsync`.

Thanks

Including relevant details from my `Startup.cs` in case I'm doing something wrong here:

I've tried a few different variants from other examples I've found but

```cs
    services
        .AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddRoles<AppRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<AppUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

    services
        .AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt()
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth:Google:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth:Google:ClientSecret"];

            options.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent"; // Hack so we always get a refresh token, it only comes on the first authorization response
            options.AccessType = "offline";
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
            options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
        })
```

And my api is simply:

```cs
[Authorize()]
[Route("test")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var all = User.Claims.Select(s => $"{s.Type}: {s.Value}");
    return Ok(all);
}
```

Comment: The documentation is a bit unclear, but doesn't the event options.Event.OnTicketReceived have the claims from after the authentication? I.e. instead of OnPostConfirmationAsync method, cant you add your claims in that event?

Comment: Probably you mess the things up: you say "since this is an SPA that page doesn't exist", but the mentioned page is a part of your Identityserver implementation, not your client app (even they hosted together). If the page doesn't exist in the template, you are free to create it. Anyway @Hyperdingo is right, and you can handle the external claims at the other place.

Comment: @Hyperdingo the claims from google appear in `OnTicketReceived` (in context.Principal.Claims), those claims just aren't there when I call my API. It seems like the identity in OnTicketReceived is different than the identity in my API. For whatever reason the claims just don't transfer over. I can add custom claims with a ProfileService but at that point I don't have access to the Google claims.

Comment: Correct, it is two different identitys. In OnTicketReceived you have your google user, and in your api it is your application user. In the link you posted to Persist additional claims, you can see that UserManager is used to find or create the application user. And then the _userManager.AddClaimAsync is used to add the claims. Not sure why in your example code the options.ClaimsAction.MapJsonKey doesnt work, but using the _userManager.AddClaimAsync to add claims to your app user in OnTicketReceived will work instead(i.e. you can access both google and app user in OnTicketReceived).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've been able to handle this is to [scaffold the needed ExternalLogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) page (like @d_f mentioned in the question's comments) and then continue following the [Persist additional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-5.0#map-user-data-keys-and-create-claims) steps. I was hoping I could just set a collection of claims to keep in my Startup file and it would work but Identity Server just uses its internal `ExternalLogin` (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Internal) and the code there doesn't handle adding external claims. This works for now but I would prefer a way of not needing to scaffold the ExternalLogin page.

I tried asking for clarification on the official docs but my question was closed (instead they suggested I ask on StackOverflow - lol). However there seems to be some work being done on improving the docs and flowing the claims through, if interested you can dig through this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16488